# Sublime Text 3 - How to hide list of commands dropdown?

Tags: search, drop-down-menu, menu, sublimetext3, show-hide

From time to time I accidentally press something in Sublime Text 3 that causes the following dropdown menu to appear:

[image]

I don't know what this dropdown is called. It's a searchable alphabetical list of commands.

There is no (X) button to close it. How do I make this go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drop down is called Command Palette.
Press `Esc` key to close it. It opens when you press the following key combinations when sublime is open:

- Mac: `Command`+`Shift`+`p`
- Windows/Linux: `Control`+`shift`+`p`

Comment: Thank you. (And welcome to StackOverflow.) It looks like we both posted answers at the same time. In any case, I hope this info will be useful for people trying to look this up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Got it... this dropdown is called the **Command Palette**.

I remembered that I had opened this before when [installing Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation). So I looked up the steps for that, and the shortcut was listed in those instructions:

Win/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>